# Update Node.js on MacOS in thermal is throwing an exception error

Tags: node.js, macos

I am trying to update Node.js on a MacOS using terminal. I type the command sudo apt install and it returns this error after the password: 
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it's recommended to just download the executable from nodejs.org and update it from there. This should do all the work for you by updating node.js and npm at the right place.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that and still receiving the same error.

Comment: have you been able to fix it? I am facing the same issue :/